# How to create an Angular library to be distributed with more than one component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create an Angular library to be distributed with more than one component but I couldn't make it work. It works with only one component. This is how I made it for one component:

I have a folder called sample-library. Inside the **src** I have:

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "sample-library",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "IG"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "sample-library.umd.js",
  "module": "sample-library.js",
  "jsnext:main": "sample-library.js",
  "typings": "sample-library.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.es5.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "stripInternal": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../build",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "sample-library.js",
    "flatModuleId": "sample-library"
  },
  "files": [
    "./index.ts"
  ]
}
```

**index.ts**:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample.component';

export * from './sample.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SampleComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SampleComponent
  ]
})
export class SampleModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: []
    };
  }
}
```

I also have **sample-library.component.hml**, **sample-library.component.scss** and **sample-library.component.ts** inside src.

This way works correctly. But I don't know how I can add another component in the same library following a similar way. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many components as you want in your ngModule's `exports` parameter, like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SampleComponent,
    SampleComponent2,
  ],
  exports: [
    SampleComponent,
    SampleComponent2,
  ]
})
```

Working example here:
https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi-angular/blob/master/src/module.ts#L118

I would recommend not to implement your ngModule in `index.ts`, but in a separated file like `module.ts`, and in `index.ts`, just export all your items (ngModule, components, services, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know htere is no "standard" way of doing this: I never saw anything in the docs.
Anyway, there are some blog posts about this, with tutorials:

- https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-library-in-angular-2-and-publish-to-npm-from-scratch-f2b1272d6266
- https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/